# how to access first output from Python loop

Tags: python, loops

I have this python loop:

```
for idx, device in enumerate(account.covers.values()):
```

so then when i do `print(device.device_id)`

I get this result:

```
chdibcb32
chdbvvo13
f82074242
```

because there is 3 devices, which is right. Now i want to access the first one only `chdibcb32`. I tried `print(device.device_id[0])`, but that just prints the first letter of each output.

how can i do this?

Comment: For the question to be complete, please share the (wrong)code that is giving you only first letter! Also any errors if you get.

Comment: It'd help if you provided a [mre], meaning an actual example of `account.covers.values()`.

Answer (score 3):

Why bother looping?

If `account.covers.values()` returns a **[sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence)**, you can use indexing to get its first element:

```
device = account.covers.values()[0]
print(device.device_id)
```

If it's an **[iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)**, you can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
device = next(account.covers.values())
```

If it's **some other [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)** (like a [dict view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) or [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)), you can use `next(iter())`:

```
device = next(iter(account.covers.values()))
```

- Sidenote: this solution is basically equivalent to:

  ```
  for device in account.covers.values():
      break
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop. You can do it like this `print(account.covers.values()[0].device_id)` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

it is because you use for each loop. Each item is using string but not list. Thats why python chose the first letter instead of the item in the list

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).